# Linked Lists are turning my brain to mush. How should I be doing this?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, pass-by-reference

I'm attempting to use linked lists as a way to buildup my knowledge of pointers in C. So, I wrote a small example but when I compile it I'm getting an error I can't seem to figure out:

```
In function 'append_node': 
error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union
```

What's the proper way to access (or pass) a structure by reference?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
  int val;
  struct node *next;
};

static int append_node(int val, struct node **head) {
  struct node *new_node;

  new_node = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  new_node->val  = val;
  new_node->next = NULL

  *(head)->next = new;

  return 0;
}

int main() {
  int i;
  struct node *head;
  struct node *curr;

  head = NULL;
  curr = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      append_node(i, &curr);
      head = curr;
  }

  curr = head;
  while(curr) {
      printf("%d\n", curr->val);
      curr = curr->next ;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: to all who replied so far: 1) the pointer to the new node is called `new_node` and not `new`.  2) by assigning the new node to `(*head)->next`, the rest of the list will be culled (and leaked): the idea is to have the new node become the new head, that's why the argument to the function is _double_ pointer to the node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can I assume you're getting the error on this line?

```
  *(head)->next = new;
```

I think you need to make one trivial change:

```
  (*head)->next = new;
```

Since `head` is a pointer to a pointer, when you dereference it you get a pointer. The `->next` operates on that pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

There is a missing `;` at the end of

```
new->next = NULL
```

and change

```
*(head)->next = new;
```

to

```
(*head)->next = new;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
(*head)->next = new_node;
```

Turn `**head` to `*head` and then call members on it.